# aspx page - download zip file with invalid error on IE 11

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Hope you can shed some light on this issue: when i try to download a zip folder from my web application on IE 11, the download process got interrupted and after resuming, the status was completed but zip file was invalid and couldn't be open.

In PRD envr, app sits on IIS 8.0 and has the above error. 
In QA envr, sits on IIS 8.5. and is working fine.

Both PRD and QA app works fine in Chrome, firefox.

Any hints that i can use to troubleshoot?

Additional Information requested:
1) Tested with and without compatibility view - same error.
2) code sample: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/bba5a50547c8dab654dd#file-downloadzipbutton-vb

Comment: Can you please share two information with us.. 1. Have u checked this problem on other PCs as well and other versions of IE? and 2. can you please share code by which user is able to download the zip.

Comment: click compatibility view and see if there lies the problem

Comment: Added in the requested info..thanks. We have work out 4 different source code changes but still to no avail. please help!